# Ember Simple Auth Base URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have an Ember app which is set up using [Ember CLI](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli) - then a Rails app that provides the RESTful API for the Ember app (the Rails app is completely separate and runs on a different url).  I'm trying to use [Ember Simple Auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) but I can't find a way to configure a different base url than the on used on the Ember app.  Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to configure that base URL for? To make Ember.SimpleAuth authorize requests to a different origin you need to whitelist these origins (see http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#Ember-SimpleAuth-setup).

To e.g. configure the Auth 2.0 authenticator or the devise authenticator to use a different endpoint then the default ones you'd reopen the classes (before running `Ember.SimpleAuth.setup`):

```
Ember.SimpleAuth.Authenticators.OAuth2.reopen({
  serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://some.other.server/token'
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to configure the base URL to point to my Rails API app which is uses Devise.  So I'm using ember-simple-auth-devise - so I guess this will do it? 

    `Ember.SimpleAuth.Authenticators.Devise.reopen({
      serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://myurl.com/users/sign_in'
    });`

Comment: Yes, the Devise authenticator will send all requests to that URL then, see docs here: http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-devise-api-docs.html#Ember-SimpleAuth-Authenticators-Devise-serverTokenEndpoint